# Flutter/dart Update

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter project with VS Code and I ended up upgrading flutter. After upgrading, when i run my project i get a `'parameter format not correct'` error:

[image: error]

I also get this:

[image]

After my app starts whenever I press something or try to type something or even scrolling the screen it looks like it's trying to cache something:

[image]

[image]

How  can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images.

Comment: first when i try to run my app it gives me ' parameter format not correct'  and then it starts running gradle task assembly debug

Comment: and then after it finishes building it gives me ' DTC,ODTC are not allowed for package :(my app name) '

Comment: and last when the app starts, whenever i try pressing or typing or scrolling anything it gives me some long message in the debug console i attach it in the image above.